# How to access property file after creating exe of java project?

Tags: java

I have a java file in which i access property file by giving the path as:

```
String path1 = test.class.getResource("Config/field.properties").getPath();
```

When i run my project in eclipse IDE it works properly.
I created runnable jar of my project and then with the help of launch4j app i created exe file of my project.
But when i run through exe, it gives me the error as:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\test\convert.jar!\Config\field.properties (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Can anyone give me suggestions for accessing property files which are present inside jar?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have that properties file in your project jar.

Comment: yes i extracted jar file manually and checked. I have property files inside jar

Comment: Is this the path: file:\D:\test\Config\field.properties? If so then use the code like: String path1 = test.class.getResource("/../Config/field.properties").getPath();

Comment: No it is inside \D:\test\convert.jar\ path. And i dont want to extract jar files